# Multiple nested routes in Ember.js having weird behaviour

Tags: ember.js

I'm starting out on Ember.js and I have a three level route for one of the pages. This is what the router map looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('tests');
    this.resource('create', function() {
        this.resource('create.questions', {path: ':test_id' }, function() {
            this.resource('create.questions.question', {path: ':question_id'});
        });
    });
});
```

In my CreateRoute, I transition onto the create/questions route using the following code:

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('create/questions', test);
```

Which works fine, but in my CreateQuestionsRoute, this code doesn't work:

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('create/questions/question', question);
```

The error received:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The route create/questions/question was not found
```

Using the Chrome Ember inspector plugin, I can see the routes are listed as such:

```
CreateRoute
CreateQuestionsRoute
CreateQuestions.QuestionRoute
```

This seems like arbitrary behaviour. There isn't much guidance on how to handle multiple nested routes. Some references told me that my route map should actually look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource('tests');
        this.resource('create', function() {
            this.resource('questions', {path: ':test_id' }, function() {
                this.resource('question', {path: ':question_id'});
            });
        });
    });
```

Whereby the route name would automatically be nested (no need for dot notations), but this did not work. Can anyone with Ember wisdom shine some light for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('tests');
    this.resource('create', function() {
        this.resource('questions', {path: ':test_id' }, function() {
            this.resource('question', {path: ':question_id'});
        });
    });
});
```

The only reason to add namespace a resource is if the resource isn't unique.  Which means from any route you can use

```
this.transitionTo('questions', model);

this.transitionTo('question', modelForQuestions, modelForQuestion);
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/636/edit

If you want to keep your namespace, I'd go with camelCase instead of dot notation, since generally the dot means property on the current scope.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/637/edit

Comment: Thank you for answering! I would however like to ask if there is a way to preserve the namespace? If I remove the dot notations, I will have to have a QuestionController, which I may need to use under a different parent route later. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: I will eventually need the questions and question resource under a separate parent. I know that 'create' sounds more like a route, but Ember doesn't allow nesting under routes

Comment: Yeah, you can totally do it, I'd avoid dot and go to camelCase.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/637/edit